# Lattice to Mesh for Cloth Simulation

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, lattice

[image: Cube with Inside Edges for higher Volume Retention during Simulation]

I recently watched a tutorial for **real-time cloth physics to simulate soft body movements**. Hair, clothes, breasts, you name it. (Link below) At one point, the operator **creates a cube and then extrudes the edge to the inside**. This gives the object a **higher volume retention than a normal cube with no interior structure** would have.

[Soft Body Jiggling Tutorial by Mas Baco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfEv5ncJCU4&t=0s&list=PLqYdtDcEzll-fdaTHkOQEVIHvpqJ9OvVv&index=52)

I have been wondering, wouldn't it be easier to use a lattice for this purpose. The problem is, lattices cannot use a Cloth Modifier, but only the computationally more expensive Soft Body Modifier. Not so great for real-time, therefore.

The solution would be to just make the Lattice Object into a Mesh Object. But I cannot find a way to do that. Is there really no way, or am I just missing it?
Convert to Mesh does not do the trick here at any rate.

Comment: So, you want to do *Lattice->Mesh* conversion instead of extruding edges as proposed in the tutorial? Doubt this is possible without scripting, but you can build "kind of lattice" mesh from Cube and 3 Array modifiers

Comment: Good point! the lattice modifier would be really easy to script and offer the kind of settings that a lattice has in terms of rows and columns. I'll see if i can build something with that.